# Simultaneous Java + Clojure development: Cider without Leiningen?

Tags: java, clojure, project-management, leiningen, cider

Here's the scenario: I am working on a project for a class that requires a Java solution: in particular, the key function receives an AI problem and returns an answer String. My intended approach is to receive the problem and, in turn, send it to a Clojure function that solves it and returns the solution String to the key function which, in turn, submits it.

My question is one of work-flow. As an avid emacs user (though new to Clojure) I'd like to get the benefits of using Cider. However, as both the Clojure and the Java portions of this project are under development, starting a new project in Leiningen doesn't seem feasible or necessary. At the moment I have built into the Java a class which deals AI problems to Clojure upon a call and I then fire up a REPL from the command-line (non-Cider) and get to work on it, saving progress in a .clj. Once I have the AI solver worked out this way, I plan to wean myself off the custom problem dealer class (not valid in the final submission) and simply pass problems from the key Java function to a primary Clojure function and get the answer String back.

**My final submission files MUST include**: KeyFunction.java

**My final submission files can also include**: myClojureFile (JAR or other Java-callable format)

So, how can I approach this while gaining the benefits of Cider (which has instructions always including a Leiningen project) when my "Project" is really in Java, in terms of final submission?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `nrepl` server provided by [`clojure.tools.nrepl`](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl) and connect to this via `cider`. You will also need to use whichever nrepl middleware your `cider` version expects. Since you are not using `lein` you will need to configure the dependency via `maven` or install it and all of its dependencies (as well as the middleware expected by your `cider` version) locally.

But by far the better solution is to just use `leiningen`, which simplifies this setup.

A `leinengen` project can contain both Clojure and Java code. As mentioned in the [tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md), lein will compile Java code, followed by compiling Clojure code.

> If you have any Java to be compiled in :java-source-paths or Clojure namespaces listed in :aot, they will always be compiled before Leiningen runs any other code, via any run, repl, etc. invocations.

Comment: So given that my clients will have a Java program that they will plug my stuff into, so I will just turn in what I mentioned above (and only what I mentioned), how will that shape out with this method you've mentioned? How would I eventually boil it down to a .java and a .jar?

Comment: the `lein uberjar` or `lein jar` commands both create a jar file containing any .clj or .java files, any resources you define, your compiled .class files, and (for the uberjar) all required third party jars.